# Usage of "if and only if" as a nontechnical term

Tags: logic

The phrase *"if and only if"* (`iff`) is commonly used in the field of mathematics (`⇔`) and computer programming, as a conditional expression in classical (Boolean) logic.

Within that scope, it might not mean the same as a simple *"if:"*

> If it rains, I will get wet.

*I will get wet if it rains, but, there are numerous ways to get wet.*

> I will get wet, if and only if it rains.

*Only rain, exclusively, can make me wet.*

Do these distinctions apply in this way (example above), outside of the aforementioned domain?

Comment: On a related note, I realized the other day that "and/or" in English (and in other natural languages) is used to represent logical inclusive or, since "or" is usually taken to be the exclusive or (this or that, but not both).

Comment: In normal writing I would usually punctuate it: *I will get wet if, and only if, it rains.*

Comment: @Henrik N: Interesting, I hadn't thought of that before. Now you got me questioning all "logical operators" in the English language! Aaah! :p

Comment: @psmears: True, it should probably be punctuated in normal writing :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say "if and only if" in regular conversation, you are taking the mathematical construction and applying it to a general life situation.  So you can say "I will get wet if and only if it rains" and mean that:

> If it is raining, I am wet.
>
> AND:
>
> If I am wet, it is raining.

(If either condition is met, the other is also met.)

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought. So, in general life situations, *"I will get wet, if and only if it rains"* also implies that there are no other possible ways to get wet? (Contra *"if"*, which implicitly leaves room for other possible causes). Is the *"if and only if"* statement void if I get wet from somebody throwing a waterballon at me? :)

Comment: That's right; If you get wet because of a water balloon and it's not raining, then your if-and-only-if statement was a false statement.  (On the other hand, if someone hit you with a water balloon while it was raining on you, you'd still be okay.)

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer! You confirmed what I thought to be the case. You must be a programmer too? :p

Comment: Can "if an only if" be shortened to just "only if" and mean exactly the same thing?

Comment: @PaulJ.Lucas, that's one of those gray areas; some people may take it that way, others may argue that "only if" implies necessity but not sufficiency--that is, "I will get wet only if it rains" means that "it rains" is the only condition under which I can get wet, but it does not mean that I *must* get wet when it rains.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it does work (though it sounds a little technical) in common language because by saying:

> I will get wet if and only if it rains.

you are saying both

> I will get wet if it rains.

(meaning that if it rains there is no chance I will not be wet) and

> I will get wet only if it rains.

(there is no way I will get wet unless it rains).

Comment: Okay, so I guess the term is a bit more "loose" when it comes to general life situations then :)